# How to access User Certificate store in Android Xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, x509

I have an android Device with an X.509 client certificate installed.
When I use a browser to access our server, the Use certificate popup shows  and the certifcate is used for authentication to access the site.
So I know the certificate is installed and works.

A piece of code that works in XAMARIN forms UWP does not work under android.
I have selected **USE_CREDENTIALS** in the Android Manifest.
Is there another permission required ?
Is there something else to do to access the User certificates on android ?

```
private X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate()
{
    using (X509Store userCaStore = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
    {
        try
        {
            userCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInStore = userCaStore.Certificates;
            // All personal certificates are available on UWP.
            // The collection is empty on Android although a cert is installed and works in other apps.
            foreach (var cert in certificatesInStore)
            {
                if (cert.FriendlyName == "MY_CERTNAME")   
                {
                    return cert;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            userCaStore.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems to need use Java.Security.KeyStore to get the certificate.

Comment: Did you find any answer ?

Comment: @NeerajGoel  No, this is an outstanding issue for me.
Our tool  still doesnt support X.509 on Android.   
Writing Java Libraries doesnt  really help.
If the standard MSAL tools arent selecting the cert , then im treating it as unspported.
It works on windows why not on Android. User should get the popup. 
Allow to App to access and supply certificate.
If forced to solve, id ask user to load the cert directly into the app and use from there.
Im not writing java code and trying to embed that project into the solution.